# openvswitch, one NIC brdiges and vlans

Tags: routes

I must change from linux-bridge to openvswitch.
I have one physical NIC which got untagged vlan from a cisco switch
I successfull set up a network using linux bridge and iproute2 (every vlan has a bridge).
I must do same using openvswitch but I am not able to ping vlan's gateway using the appropriate bridge connnected to the specific vlan.

here is what I did (ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS):

specify vlans in the interfaces file:

```
/etc/network/interfaces

auto vlan300
iface vlan300 inet manual
vlan-raw-device eth1

auto vlan302
iface vlan302 inet manual
vlan-raw-device eth1
```

openvswitch configuration:

```
ovs-vsctl add-br mgmnt
ovs-vsctl add-port mgmnt vlan300

ovs-vsctl add-br dmz
ovs-vsctl add-port dmz vlan302
```

iproute2 configuration:

```
ip route add 172.40.1.0/24 dev mgmnt src 172.40.1.1 table vlan300
ip route add default via 172.40.1.254 dev mgmnt table vlan300
ip rule add from 172.40.1.0/24 table vlan300
ip rule add to 172.40.1.1 table vlan300

ip addr add 172.40.1.1/24 dev mgmnt 
ip link set mgmnt up

ip route add 172.50.1.0/24 dev dmz src 172.50.1.1 table vlan302
ip route add default via 172.50.1.254 dev dmz table vlan302
ip rule add from 172.50.1.0/24 table vlan302
ip rule add to 172.50.1.1 table vlan302

ip addr add 172.50.1.1/24 dev dmz
ip link set dmz up
```

At this point I have the mgmnt and dmz interface with IP address, routing information.

Bu I cannot ping the vlan's gateway, and I cannot ping the interface's IP address from an other machine in same vlan.

What do I missed?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've figured out the solution.
There is a unnecessary ip policy rule in the above design.
removing the

```
ip rule add to 172.40.1.1 table vlan300
```

and

```
ip rule add to 172.50.1.1 table vlan302
```

clause, solved the problem.